# I tried running Vercel locally but did not work

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am developing a project using Next Js and I use Vercel as a my server, I Need to run Vercel locally, but when I do I get the following errors.

```
Vercel Dev
```

Here are the errors.

```
> Running Dev Command “vite --port $PORT”
'cmd.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\vercel\dist\index.js:178102:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\vercel\dist\index.js:178136:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\vercel\dist\index.js:178123:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
Error: An unexpected error occurred!
Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\vercel\dist\index.js:178102:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\vercel\dist\index.js:178136:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\vercel\dist\index.js:178123:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)

JS@Udemezue MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Copy-and-Post/ui-copyandpost (sit)
$ vercel dev
Vercel CLI 28.10.1
> Running Dev Command “vite --port $PORT”
'cmd.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\vercel\dist\index.js:178102:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\vercel\dist\index.js:178136:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\vercel\dist\index.js:178123:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
Error: An unexpected error occurred!
Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\vercel\dist\index.js:178102:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\vercel\dist\index.js:178136:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\vercel\dist\index.js:178123:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved, I did not install Vercel Locally

```
npm install -g vercel
```

Do this and it should work just fine.